# How do I can get path for dict in dict in Python?

Tags: python

There is dictionary which is generated by adding some data:

```
some_dict = {'some_value1': {}, 'dict1': {'qwerty': None, 'bar': {}}}
```

I know that I can add there some data by using update method:

```
some_dict['dict1']['bar'].update({'some_key': value})
```

But what if a part of the code doesn't know correct way to update 'bar'?
like:

```
some_dict[???]['bar'].update({'some_key': value})
```

How can I update it correctly?

Comment: Note, you shouldn't be using `.update` to modify a single key. Just use `some_dict[some_key] = some_value`

Comment: Do you mean you want to search through `some_dict` to find `bar`? Or do you mean you want to use a variable in place of `???`?

Comment: In short, you can't. You have to either iterate over entire dictionary to find the required key or maintain another dictionary which contains path for every key

Comment: Anyway, if you have no knowledge of the dict contents, then you'll have to search the data structure. This is not ideal. You should structure your program to not have to do that

Comment: This smells like an x-y question/problem. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard Python function to do what you want. You will need to implement some kind of search algorithm yourself. Broadly speaking you will have the choice between a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) strategy.

A possible implementation of the former would be something along the lines of:

```
some_dict = {'some_value1': {}, 'dict1': {'qwerty': None, 'bar': {}}}

def get_nested_dict(d, name):
    stack = [d]
    while stack:
        for k, v in stack.pop().items():
            if k == name:
                return v

            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append(v)


print(some_dict)
get_nested_dict(some_dict, 'bar')['new'] = 1
print(some_dict)
```

Producing:

```
{'some_value1': {}, 'dict1': {'qwerty': None, 'bar': {}}}
{'some_value1': {}, 'dict1': {'qwerty': None, 'bar': {'new': 1}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I want to clarify your question. The problem is that you have a dictionary within a dictionary and (i.e. `overall_dict = {..., 'inner_dict' : {'foo': 4 }}`) and what you want is for a function to update 'foo' without passing in `overall_dict`? I.e the function below

```
def func1(dict): 
   dict['foo'] = 6
```

If that is the case, then there isn't too much of a problem. Python uses pointers and therefore if you pass `func1(overall_dict['inner_dict'])` then it will do what you want. Essentially you can set a variable to point to the inner dictionary. When you update the new variable, then it will also update the `overall_dict`.

I hope that helps. If you are wondering about other python dictionary questions, 
[pythontutor.com](https://www.pythontutor.com)

My tests to make sure python is by pointers is [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%7B'dic1'%20%3A%20%7B'bar'%3A%204%7D,%20'blah'%20%3A%204%7D%0Ab%20%3D%20a%5B'dic1'%5D%0Ab%5B'bar'%5D%20%3D%206&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

This is also a really good textbook for python: [link here](http://composingprograms.com/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: gnahum, I will take a look to your provided links, indeed the way I have choosed is too complicated. Looking for other ways to re-write this part of the code. Thanks for your help.